# mp4 metadata extraction in Python

Tags: python, json, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have a program that has to edit several videos based off of data in a separate json-file. These videos are sequential and they have metadata in their own json file. The program edits them with a frame-by-frame overlay (eye-tracking data).

What I'd like to do is compare individual mp4 metadata with the json-file metadata so I can compare timestamps, making sure everything is synchronized.

If possible, how would I get to the mp4 metadata?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [mp4file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mp4file/0.2) module for this.

`pip install mp4file`

[Example from here](https://github.com/billnapier/mp4file/blob/master/src/example.py)

```py
from mp4file.mp4file import Mp4File

def find_metadata_atom(file, name):
    atom = file.find('.//%s//data' % name)
    return atom.get_attribute('data')

file = Mp4File("bill.mp4")

title = find_metadata_atom(file, 'title')
tvshow = find_metadata_atom(file, 'tvsh')
```

Comment: Works in theory, but the people who wrote the system for the "grouped" metadata didn't actually give me relevant data. Just found that out. Thanks for the response. I think I'll just load the entire batch in and work from there.

Comment: @TerraCode I see. Sorry to hear that. If you think the answer might be usefull for others, I would  appreciate a upvote or accept. If not, no offence ;)

Comment: When I run your code, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atom'`

And if I install atom, I then get:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_atoms' from 'atom' (/home/rolf/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/atom/__init__.py)`

Comment: @Endlisnis I think this was written with python2